# Qml TextField - teclado numérico

Tags: ios, teclado, qml

Estou tentando usar um `TextField` que receba apenas números `QML`. Estpu usando a propriedade `inputMethodHints` para fazer o dispositivo mostrar apenas o teclado numérico. Funciona bem no Android mas quando eu rodo no iOS ele mostra o teclado completo com dígitos, caracteres e as palavras sugeridas.

Código abaixo:

```
TextField {
    id: numeroTelefoneTextField

    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.right: parent.right

    width: parent.width * 0.70
    height: parent.height * 0.6

    placeholderText: qsTr("Seu número")

    font.bold: true

    validator: RegExpValidator{regExp: /\d+/}

    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
}
```

Eu tentei outras opções como `inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly | Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText` e apenas `inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText` mas nenhuma destas opções funciona no iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema removendo os `validators`, mas eu não sei porque só funcionou sem o validadores.

Código abaixo:

```
TextField {
    id: numeroTelefoneTextField

    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.right: parent.right

    width: parent.width * 0.70
    height: parent.height * 0.6

    placeholderText: qsTr("Seu número")

    font.bold: true

    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
}
```